# Where does Html.DropDownList return the selected value to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a dropdownlist in my mvc application, but am very confused by how it operates. It appears that you pass the list that appears in the dropdown, and a temporary description, but never tell it where you would like the selected value stored. Am I missing something or how do I retrieve a value from my drop-down list?

My drop-down list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeNames", null, "Select an Employee", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

My current drop-down list appears correctly but I am unable to retain the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You tell where the value to be stored, the property `EmployeeNames` from the current `Model`.

You can take a look at [MVC Model Binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/551576/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-and-Data-Annotation). The first parameter of [`DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492738.aspx) is the `name`. The MVC bind the value by the form elements `name`.

The following

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeNames", null, "Select an Employee", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In HTML will look similar to this

```
<select id="EmployeeNames" name="EmployeeNames">
   <!-- options -->
</select>
```

You notice `name="EmployeeNames"`, that will help to bind to the property `EmployeeNames` from the curent `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's pretty straightforward.. just grab the variable on the method call which handle the particular form action in your controller, if the name of your DropDownList is `EmployeeNames` , then your method should look like this

```cs
public ActionResult handleForm(string employeeNames)
{
   return View();
}
```